# make a search box case insensitive

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('#asearch').on('input', function(){
 let a = $(this).val();
 $('.title').hide();
 $('.title:contains(' + a + ')').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = 'search' class='asearch' id='asearch' placeholder='Search'>
<div class='title'>loRem</div>
<div class='title'>IpsuM</div>
```

I want to get the first title visible if `lor` is typed inside the search box and the second title if `i` is typed i.e. want the search box to be case insensitive.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:contains` selector in jquery is `case sensitive`. You can use regex with `filter()`

```js
$('#asearch').on('input', function() {
  let a = $(this).val();
  $('.title').hide();
  $('.title').filter(function() {
    return new RegExp(a, 'i').test($(this).text())
  }).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='search' class='asearch' id='asearch' placeholder='Search'>
<div class='title'>loRem</div>
<div class='title'>IpsuM</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the .contains filter to be case insensitive or create your own selector.

```
 jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
      .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
```

```js
jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
      .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};


$('#asearch').on('input', function(){
 let a = $(this).val();
 $('.title').hide();
 $('.title:contains(' + a + ')').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = 'search' class='asearch' id='asearch' placeholder='Search'>
<div class='title'>loRem</div>
<div class='title'>IpsuM</div>
```